# ¿Cómo hacer un Remmapping "Remapear" de ciertas teclas en GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, gnu

El caso es que quiero hacer un remmaping al combinar las teclas <kbd>Alt GR</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> que se obtiene esta salida:

```
{
```

Bien con **xev** puedo ver bastante informacion de las teclas pulsadas.

Por ejemplo para si quisiera mapear la <kbd>v</kbd>:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 64, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
root 0xb3, subw 0x0, time 16749228, (-346,368), root:(373,548),
state 0x10, keycode 55 (keysym 0x76, v), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (76) "v"
```

donde la <kbd>x</kbd>

```
root 0xb3, subw 0x0, time 16789556, (-254,241), root:(465,421),
state 0x10, keycode 53 (keysym 0x78, x), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (78) "x"
```

Usaria **xmodmap** con este comando (que seria valido para la secion):

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 53 = v"
```

---

con este tipo no tengo problemas, el problema bien al querer mapear `{` que se produce con <kbd>Alt GR</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>

```
root 0xb3, subw 0x0, time 16817964, (-157,185), root:(562,365),
state 0x90, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
```

.

```
root 0xb3, subw 0x0, time 17000717, (359,-47), root:(361,389),
state 0x90, keycode 16 (keysym 0x7d, braceleft), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (7d) "{"
```

---

he intentado varias formas:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 53 = {"
xmodmap:  commandline:1:  bad keysym name '{' in keysym list
xmodmap:  1 error encountered, aborting.
```

tambien he intentado el mapeo de <kbd>7</kbd> sin el uso de <kbd>Alt GR</kbd>

```
state 0x10, keycode 16 (keysym 0x37, 7), same_screen YES,
```

.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = 7"
```

Aunque este ultimo si funciona al combinar la nueva tecla con <kbd>Alt GR</kbd> para generar `{` no funciona.

---

He pensado que quizas ese tipo de combinaciones en mas cosa del hardware, que combina las pistas internas del teclado, y por eso no funciona, el caso es que no se a que se debe, si es que lo estoy haciendo mal, o para esas teclas se debe hacer de otra manera o simplemente "no se puede".

---

*P.D: No se si este tipo de preguntas es valida yo creo que si en el meta se hablo sobre ello pero no se si habra cambiado.*

Comment: ya di con el error, esperare un poco por si alguien esta haciendo una respuesta, para la pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

el error que estaba cometiendo era:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 64, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
root 0xb3, subw 0x0, time 16749228, (-346,368), root:(373,548),
state 0x10, keycode 55 (keysym 0x76, v), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (76) "v"
```

aqui -> `....v), same_screen YES,`

aqui -> `.... "v"`

como pude ver la `v` esta en los dos lados y yo tomaba como referencia entre todas las linas que generaba **xev**, la **segunda** linea de la `v`, no habia problema porque al fijarme coincidian la `v` en ambas lineas cosa que no sucede con `{`:

```
state 0x90, keycode 16 (keysym 0x7d, braceleft), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (7d) "{"
```

aqui -> `.... braceright), same_screen YES,`

aqui -> `...."}"`

---

yo usaba:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 53 = {"
```

pero tendria que usar:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 53 = braceleft"
```

tomando solo como referencia esta linea:

```
state 0x90, keycode 16 (keysym 0x7d, braceleft), same_screen YES,
```

aqui -> `keycode 16` aqui -> `braceleft)` he igual para la nueva tecla con su respectiva linea.